# NullPointerException when calling getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

This code stop working, the only thing I have done is change to Android 4.0.3

```
public class PrinterFunctions 
{ 
 private static SharedPreferences mSetup;
 public static final String CSDT = "ComDT";

     public static void printFast(){
            final Context myContext = null;
            loadCompany(myContext);
     }     

     public static void loadCompany(Context context){

     mSetup = context.getSharedPreferences(CSDT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // NullPointException

         //code here

     }
}
```

I get the NullPointerException when executing the above line, this code use to work fine.

Thanks for any help.
Kim

Comment: `CSDT` what is it ???? i didnt see CSDT in your class so give that a name or you can pass the string directly... And are you passing proper context ??

Comment: post your logcat output also.from where you call to loadCompany method?

Comment: Do you have `CSDT` one of your key in SharedPreferences? This may be the probable reason.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `loadCompany()`. From you description it seems that context is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting a NPE on that particular line, it probably means the `context` you are passing to `loadCompany()` is `null`.

Comment: Yes it is null and if I try to use 'this' I get an error saying that I cant use it in a static context. I edit the question.

Comment: I change the code to include the Context from the activity that call the class. This works.